# ReRender RichFaces element stored in a4j:included page

Tags: richfaces

I've got a panelMenu in an a4j:included xhtml page included in another JSF page.  When an a4j:commandButton is hit in the parent page, some data changes in the included file and I'd like to reRender an element storing it.  In the example snippet below, `controlPanel` is  reRendered as part of this operation but this doesn't seem to be enough.

When the app first loads, it looks to reRender the element in the a4j:included page directly (if I put it in the reRender attribute list) but the console warns as it's not included yet.

Is there a way round this?

Parent:

```
<rich:toolBarGroup location="right">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="controlPanel">
                        <a4j:region>
                            <a4j:include viewId="#{MyBacking.ctrlBox}">
                                <f:param name="targetIdParam" value="controls" />
                            </a4j:include>
                        </a4j:region>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </rich:toolBarGroup>
```